# Eclipse upgrade from Neon to Oxygen losing workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon, eclipse-oxygen

When I upgrade my Eclipse after restart Eclipse say that Oxygen use new workspace. But when I start Eclipse next time it starts as - old Neon. With old workspace.

So I don't know where are data Oxygen stores.

And I can't find it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse requires a workspace definition on first time start.
It can be managed from File > Switch Workspace

Set your new eclipse workspace to the old work space and you can find your projects there. If still they aren't visible, you can always import them into the new eclipse.

Hope I helped.

Comment: If you want to see where your Oxygen eclipse stores it workspace, you can see from File > Switch Workspace > Other 

Then the workspace in use will come pre loaded.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer but...
I have had Neon, then I upgraded to Oxygen and Oxygen changed things about worspace to new way of working...but when I started Eclipse instead Oxygen starts Neon. And I don't know where is workspace of Oxygen (which I don't have now)
I ask for default path of Oxygen workspace.